# Correct format for tech report in bibliography using APA style

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I'm trying to get my tech reports to format correctly when I use APA style.  Specifically, the last two entries should be place-of-publication:publisher.  I can get the Bibliography right if I don't use APA, but then my citations in text will be just numbers...

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
%\usepackage{biblatex}  % comment above and uncomment this one and the bibliography will be correct, but the citations in text will not be APA style.

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@techreport{myreport,
author = {John Smith and Kelly Clarkson},
institution = {Far away labs},
title = "A very cool experiment",
type = {report},
number= {0005},
address = {anywhere, US},
year = {2018},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item This is my citation \cite{myreport}
\end{itemize}

\printbibliography[title=REFERENCES]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/references/examples/report-individual-authors-references a technical report should be cited in APA style (7th ed.) as

> Stuster, J., Adolf, J., Byrne, V., & Greene, M. (2018). *Human exploration of Mars: Preliminary lists of crew tasks* (Report No. NASA/CR-2018-220043). National Aeronautics and Space Administration. https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20190001401.pdf

so arguably the result that `biblatex-apa` currently produces

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@techreport{myreport,
  author      = {John Smith and Kelly Clarkson},
  institution = {Far away labs},
  title       = {A very cool experiment},
  type        = {report},
  number      = {0005},
  address     = {anywhere, US},
  year        = {2018},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{myreport}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Smith, J., & Clarkson, K. (2018). A very cool experiment (Rep. No. 0005). Far away labs. anywhere, US.]

is almost correct, but probably should not show the `location`/`address` at all. That could be achieved like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \pertype{report}
      \pertype{techreport}
      \step[fieldset=address, null]
      \step[fieldset=location, null]
    }
  }
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@techreport{myreport,
  author      = {John Smith and Kelly Clarkson},
  institution = {Far away labs},
  title       = {A very cool experiment},
  type        = {report},
  number      = {0005},
  address     = {anywhere, US},
  year        = {2018},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{myreport}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok.  Interesting didn't realize APA had a new style manual out.  I need to get the technical writer/administrator to agree to change to the latest.  I'll check this as complete once she does.  Otherwise, I still might need to format the old way.  Regardless, thanks for the prompt reply.